# write x in terms of y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

given
$f: (-1, 1] -  \{0\} \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = 1/x - x$

let y $\in$ $R$, f(x) = y

I want to write $f(x)$ in terms of $y$, but I'm so stuck and don't know how to proceed. Should this be written as a piece wise function in terms of $y$?

Comment: Beware that there is no $y$ in yourproblem statement.

Comment: sorry i was in a hurry. it's been fixed

Comment: Hem, you still don't say what $y$ is.

Answer (score 1):

If

$$y=\frac1x-x$$ then

$$x^2+yx-1=0.$$

Solve the quadratic equation for $x$.

Comment: @Bungo: yep, fixed, thanks.

Comment: Oh thanks man! I should just go for the easy way. I was overthinking too much